# strange year values on X axis

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

If I use the vega dataset "disasters" and make a straightforward chart, I get some weird values for year.

#### In Altair the code is:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

dis=data.disasters()

alt.Chart(dis).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:T'),
    y=alt.Y('Deaths'),
    color='Entity'
)
```

[image]

[(vega editor link)](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding to @kanitw's answer: when you convert an integer to a datetime, the integer is treated as nanoseconds since the zero date. You can see this in pandas by executing the following:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(dis.Year)
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001900
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001901
2   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001902
3   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001903
4   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001905
Name: Year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Altair/Vega-Lite uses a similar convention.

If you would like to parse the year as a date when loading the data, and then plot the year with Altair, you can do the following:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

dis=data.disasters(parse_dates=['Year'])

alt.Chart(dis).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year(Year):T'),
    y=alt.Y('Deaths'),
    color='Entity'
)
```

[image: example chart]

First we parse the year column as a date by passing the appropriate `pandas.read_csv` argument to the loading function, and then use the `year` [timeUnit](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform.html#timeunit-transform) to extract just the year from the full datetime.

If you are plotting data from a CSV URL rather than a pandas dataframe, Vega-Lite is smart enough to parse the CSV file based on the encoding you specify in the Chart, which means the following will give the same result:

```
dis=data.disasters.url

alt.Chart(dis).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year(Year):T'),
    y=alt.Y('Deaths:Q'),
    color='Entity:N'
)
```

[image: example chart]

Comment: Thanks Jake. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Year integer is not a standard time value.

In Vega-Lite you can add `"format": {"parse": {"Year": "date: '%Y'"}}` to the data block to specify custom date parsing format for the field `"year"`.

[See a working spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

In Altair, you can similarly specify `format` property of a *Data class (e.g., [`NamedData`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.NamedData.html#altair.NamedData)).

Comment: Thanks @kanitw. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with using `parse_dates` in pandas, is that you change the precision of your data from yearly to daily timestamps (ie from `1999`, `2000`, etc to `1999-01-01`, `2000-01-01`, etc). This also creates undesirable labels in altair if you use the date as a categorical variable for e.g. faceting or coloring.

An alternative approach that avoids this issue is to cast the year column as a string instead, which keeps the four digit year in the data and only converts it to a timestamp in Altair/Vega-Lite when the `:T` suffix is appended:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

dis=data.disasters()
dis['Year'] = dis['Year'].astype(str)

alt.Chart(dis).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('year(Year):T'),
    y=alt.Y('Deaths'),
    color='Entity'
)
```

More discussion about this can be found in these two issues:

- https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/3140
- https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1681